# Problem generating and downloading a PDF with a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, partial-views

I am currently working on a platform that allows to download invoices in PDF format.
To do this I used a partial view. When I test the local generation everything works fine. The problem comes when I book my project on our server (windows 2016 server)

I put logs to know where the problem is coming from and I have the following error:

```
An unhandled exception has occurred: Cannot return null from an action method with a return type of 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult'
```

This error seems to occur as I move to the next item :

```
var viewContext = new ViewContext(actionContext,viewResult.View,viewDictionary,new TempDataDictionary(actionContext.HttpContext, _tempDataProvider),sw,new HtmlHelperOptions());
```

Below are the different initializations of the elements present in the viewContext variable

```
var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext { RequestServices = _serviceProvider };

var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());

var sw = new StringWriter();

var viewResult = _razorViewEngine.FindView(actionContext, "MyAccount/InvoiceTemplate", false);

 var viewDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary()){Model = viewModel};
```

_tempDataProvider is initialized at the beginning of my controller.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Why did you use a partial view? Views should contain HTML. They shouldn't contain PDF's.

Comment: @mason I use a partial view that allows me to generate the HTML that will compose my PDF.